# cron job in codeigniter on cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

my controller cron_jobs in user folder and method is job

```
class Cron_jobs extends CI_Controller {
    function Cron_jobs()
     {
        parent::__construct();
     }

    function job() {
        if($this->input->is_cli_request()) {
            echo "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

in cpanel i try some of ans i find

```
http://www.my_site.com/user/cron_jobs/job

wget http://www.my_site.com/user/cron_jobs/job

curl --silent http://my_site.com/user/cron_jobs/job

php index.php user/cron_jobs job

wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.my_site.com/user/cron_jobs/job

wget -q http://www.my_site.com/user/cron_jobs/job

/usr/local/bin/php /home/my_site/public_html/index.php/user/cron_jobs/job
```

non of this are working for me....any one hving any idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.my_site.com/user/cron_job/job
```

and change the time as */5 * * * * for testing.

message sending every 5 minutes

Comment: This code working for me perfectly . Are you using any mail function to this cron.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with one of your examples!

Try:

```
php index.php user cron_jobs job
```

Hope this helps!

However, if the above doesn't work please have a look at this [Link](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/233567/#1066560).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `php index.php user/cron_jobs job` try `php-cli index.php user/cron_jobs job`

Some servers require the php-cli for command line interface execution.